# Number Format Exception while decrypting the string

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am trying to decryt the encrypted string by using the following methods,but got stuck with the Exception.

I am trying to send my encrypted string to the below method,but it couldnt able to get byte[],getting Number Format Exception while converting String to byte[].

My Decryption Method:

```
public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {

   byte[] seedByte = seed.getBytes();

   System.arraycopy(seedByte, 0, key, 0, ((seedByte.length < 16) ? seedByte.length : 16));

   String base64 = new String(Base64.decode(encrypted, 0));

  byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seedByte);

   byte[] enc = toByte(base64);

   byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);

   return new String(result);

  }
```

Here is my toByte(String) method :

```
  public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {

   int len = hexString.length() / 2;

   byte[] result = new byte[len];

   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)

    result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16).byteValue();

   return result;

  }
```

Exception I am getting :

```
08-15 13:03:04.748: W/System.err(10013): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "@��"
08-15 13:03:04.748: W/System.err(10013):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
08-15 13:03:04.748: W/System.err(10013):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
08-15 13:03:04.748: W/System.err(10013):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
08-15 13:03:04.748: W/System.err(10013):    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:510)
08-15 13:03:04.748: W/System.err(10013):    at com.example.aes.EncodeDecodeAES.toByte(EncodeDecodeAES.java:226)
08-15 13:03:04.748: W/System.err(10013):    at com.example.aes.EncodeDecodeAES.decrypt(EncodeDecodeAES.java:69)
08-15 13:03:04.748: W/System.err(10013):    at com.example.aes.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:94)
```

I really didnt understand why I am getting this error.

Please suggest.

Comment: Don't have a IDE here but could it be, that it is an charset problem?

Comment: I didnt know  what to do.can you give me any suggestions

Comment: try for encoding/decoding this packages:
sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
sun.misc.BASE64Encoder

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here is the parsing to the byte array you do here:

```
result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16).byteValue();
```

You can try this approach (considering a 4 byte Integer and that you want to split the hexString into two digit Integers):

```
byte[][] result = new byte[len][4];
int[] numbers = new int[len];
for(int j = 0; j < len ; j++){
  numbers[j] = Integer.parseInt(hexString.substring(2 * j, 2 * j + 2);
}

for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
  result[i][3] = (byte) numbers[i] & 0xFF);//No need for shifting here
  for(j = 0; j < len-1; j++){
    result[i][j] = (byte) ((numbers[i]  >> ((-1)*j*8+24)) & 0xFF);
  }
}
```

The problem with your implementation is that you split the string into several integers and you're assigning to a byte_array[0] just the first byte of the integer, then to byte_array[1] the first byte of the second integer. Know that the whole byte array of length 4 is used to store a single Integer.

Comment: where I need to use my hexString here

Comment: please suggest ,where should I use my hexString

Comment: result[i][j] = (byte) ((numbers[i]  >> ((-1)*j*8+24)) & 0xFF);  I am getting errors at this line

Comment: Please tell me what they are, I don't seem to be able to find them on first sight.

Comment: I found that if my Encrypted string contains special characters like /,+ , I think this is why I am getting error

Comment: Yeah, you sure havo to remove those (only digits must be present) if you want to use Integer to byte conversion (you can take the ASCII codes of every symbol too, I don't know if that's suitable). **one more thing** As I mentioned in the answer, there's an error in your algorythm, because - Integer is ideally 4 bytes long (this might vary rom system to system, but here is it 4). To put this integer in bytes_array[], know that 4 bytes makes the Integer, thus you'll need bytes_array[] of length 4 to store a single one. You're using byte_array of length 4 to store 4 Integers - this is false.

Comment: I used another string which has no special characters,it is working fine but now my encrypted string has +,/. I think this is the problem

Comment: Well, you can trim those from the string and obtain a String of numbers.

Comment: when I try to convert my encrypted string to base64 string I am getting something like "@??......................",I am getting error at the first place itself.I am getting AlphaNumericals while tried with another strings.

Comment: I've two propositions for you about this conversion: 1. http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/ 2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html and https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Base64.java.

Comment: And a bonus one from me: `String text = "WhateverString";byte[] data = null;
try {
data = seed.getBytes("UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] data1 = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String seed1 = null;
try {
seed1 = new String(data1, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some invalid bytes in your hex string. Try validating it before you put it into your byte array e.g do something like this:

```
    if(new Scanner(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16).hasNextInt())
         result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16).byteValue()
```

Comment: Its going inside of this if condition. please suggest any other solution

Comment: what exactly the line EncodeDecodeAES.java:226 corresponds to ?

Comment: result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16).byteValue();   this refers to that line